# Problems with Kendo UI Grid Editing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, inline-editing

I tried use the Kendo Grid and i found some problems.

The button action "edit" and "remove " do nothing when i click, but if i put the "create" command into the transport, the grid send lots of POSTS for the create URL command when i click in delete or click in edit > cancel (the update button do nothing too).

What I doing wrong?

My code:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="toolbar">      
    <input type="number" min="0" id="item-id" maxlength="10"  />
    <input type="text" id="name" class="k-textbox" placeholder="..." />
    <button style="width: 100px" id="btn-grid-filtrar" class="k-button" >Filter</button>
</div>
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
        {
            schema: 
            {
                data: "data",
                total: "total",
                model: 
                {
                    id: "data",
                    fields: 
                    {
                        id: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                        nome: { type: "string", validation: { required: true} },
                        ativo: { type: "boolean" }
                    }
                }
            },                  
            transport: 
            {
                read: 
                {
                    url: "page",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: additionalData
                },
                update: {
                    url: "update",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "delete",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
                /*,
                create: {
                    url: "add",
                    dataType: "jsonp"                   
                }
                */
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverPaging: true,
        });

        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                input: true,
                numeric: false
            },
            batch: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "id", title: "#", width: "60px" }, 
                { field: "nome", title: "Nome" }, 
                { field: "ativo", title: "Ativo", width: "60px", template: "#= ativo ? 'Sim' : 'Não' #" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Ações", width: "200px" }
            ],
            editable: "inline",
            toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),             
        });

        kendo.bind($(".toolbar"));

        $("#id").kendoNumericTextBox({
            format: "##########",
            placeholder: "..."
        });

        $("#btn-grid-filtrar").click(function() {
            grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        });
    });

    function additionalData() {
        return {
            filtro_id: $("#item-id").val(),
            filtro_nome: $("#name").val()
        };
    }

</script>
```

Comment: When you say "lots of posts", do you mean that when you click on a command button, you are seeing multiple requests rather than just one to the expected URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'm assuming that you server is serving a JSON with the following format:

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "data" : [
        {
            "data" : 23,
            "id"   : 1,
            "ativo": true,
            "nome" : "stock-1"
        },
        {
            "data" : 34,
            "id"   : 2,
            "ativo": false,
            "nome" : "stock-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Correct?

So the first thing is changing the "data" on each row `data` to something not called `data`. It turns out that `data` is a kind-of reserved word in KendoUI commonly used in code structures as:

```
with (data) {
    // Expanded code coming from a grid row data
}
```

Where this `data` is a variable referencing a row in your grid. So, in this context `data` is both the row itself and and a field in that row and then JavaScript cannot correctly solve it.

So you can define your schema as:

```
schema       : {
    data : "data",
    total: "total",
    model: {
        id    : "_data",
        fields: {
            id   : { editable: false, nullable: false },
            nome : { type: "string", validation: { required: true} },
            ativo: { type: "boolean" }
        }
    }
},
```

NOTE: I've replace `data` by `_data`.

Transmitted data is:

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "data" : [
        {
            "_data" : 23,
            "id"   : 1,
            "ativo": true,
            "nome" : "stock-1"
        },
        {
            "_data" : 34,
            "id"   : 2,
            "ativo": false,
            "nome" : "stock-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Just with this small change your `Edit` button will start working.

Comment: Thx @OnaBai. Problem solved. I change my model ID and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to define transport level for local datasources, if  understand correctly  your code, you are not posting anywhere - you are not binding any remote data,  I can't see any url ? Follow this example http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/index.html.

Comment: My code works fine now. The url: "update" points to correctly destiny. I just dont put the full URL such as the kendo example http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html.